# How to tag a passing build in jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I saw a configuration option that allows tagging every build, but it seems this would just needlessly pollute the tag history. Is there a way in Jenkins to tag a build only once it has been marked as passed?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the Git plugin's "Git Publisher" post-build step, and check the "Push Only If Build Succeeds" and "Add Tag" options.